# jquery param() does not encode parameter properly which have "&" included

Tags: javascript, url, jquery, parameters

My Application is based on Ajax request/response. I create object of all parameters and make query string using jquery param() method. it works fine but when some parameter contains "&" in it then it does not encode that properly and so server returns error in that case. Can somebody tell me how to create query string in this case when data contains "&" character?

```
var url = "http://www.abc.com"
    url += "?username='abc'";
    url += "&" + $.param(params);

/*
   params values are follows:

   params[name] = 'test'
   params[id] = 1234
   params[xyz] = 'entertainment & games'
*/
```

Also suggest if I have to change something in serverside script to decode this properly

Comment: It works for me... I get this: `&name=test&id=1234&xyz=entertainment+%26+games`. Can you post a complete code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) method encodes as expected. This snippet...:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
jQuery(function($){
    var params = {
        name: "test",
        id: 1234,
        xyz: "entertainment & games"
    };

    var url = ""
    url += "&" + $.param(params);

    alert(url);
});
//--></script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

... alerts this: `&name=test&id=1234&xyz=entertainment+%26+games`

You don't say what the error is but it's worth noting that a valid query string should begin with `?` rather than `&`:

```
var url = ""
url += "?" + $.param(params);
```

Comment: hey thanks... I got the problem in my code. Actually the content was populating dynamically in my "li" element where "entertainment & games" appear and I was reading using $("li").html(), so it was returning something like this "entertainment &amp; games" and then I was putting the same in $.param(). Now I have changed that with $("li").text(). BTY Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A little consideration:

Probabily that the error was generated by the "'abc'" value for "username" parameter...

> ```
> url += "?username='abc'";
> ```

The correct way should be:

> ```
> url += "?username=abc";
> ```